# How to view a PDF file from Firestore database in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

**MyQuestion:**

What is the best way to display a PDF file received from firestore database in Flutter and is there any recommended PDF display library that can be used for this purpose?

**Code Snippet:**

```
try {
      await _firestore
          .collection('users')
          .doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid)
          .collection('myorders')
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        myordersname = value.
        docs.map((e) => e.data()['name'])
        .toList();
        getbookdetails();
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```

**MyScreenshot:**
[image: this is my firebase database query,table]

Comment: can you explain what you want to achieve and what have you tried?

Comment: you have saved link of pdf in your database, so do you want to  get the link and show it on the screen?